# Is Spark ALS user-user or item-item collaborative filtering?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

Collaborative filtering seems to fall into two main categories; user-user and item-item.

Some [examples](https://www.slideshare.net/navisro/recommender-system-navisroanalytics):

- user-user similarity: *Users like you who bought beer also bought diapers (Target)*.
- item-item similarity: *You like godfather so you will also like scarface (Netflix)*.

What approach is taken by Apache Spark's [ALS](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-collaborative-filtering.html) implementation?

---

**Update**

I don't think matrix factorization falls into either of the above categories.  *Source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0sJMMbjjjZM (44:00 minutes in)*

Comment: your update is correct, see memory-based vs model-based collaborative filtering, high level description on wikipedia
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collaborative_filtering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding my update as an answer so this can be closed.

I don't think matrix factorization falls into either of the above categories.  *Source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0sJMMbjjjZM (44:00 minutes in)*